# Navigating to page increases memory usage Windows Universal 8.1

Tags: windows, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm creating a Windows Universal 8.1 application. Everytime I navigate to a page and then navigate back and then to the page again a new instance of the page is being held in memory. Obviously the garbage collector frees the memory after a while, however I'd rather not use the memory if it's unneeded. Is there a way to recycle or dispose of these pages?

Comment: You can use NavigationCacheMode to do it, read my answer please.@WereWolfBoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Uriversal App, We can use **NavigationCacheMode** to `recycle` a page. It can be set in the constructor of the page. For example, there is a MainPage we want to recycle:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Set the NavigationCacheMode of Page to Enabled. 
    // The page is cached, but the cached instance is discarded when the size 
    //     of the cache for the frame is exceeded.
    this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;

    // OR Set the NavigationCacheMode of Page to Required. 
    // The page is cached and the cached instance is reused for every visit 
    //     regardless of the cache size for the frame.
    // this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Required;
}
```

After setting it, We can go back to MainPage without re-create it.

If NavigationCacheMode is set to **Disabled**. The memory of page will be **released** when **OnNavigatedFrom** from it.

There is a similar question as SO: [Page constructor gets called again when navigating back in Windows 8 C# App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633758/page-constructor-gets-called-again-when-navigating-back-in-windows-8-c-sharp-app)

Comment: And how about pages you don't want to recycle but want to dispose of? Do you do this with Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Disabled ? Or is it being held in memory then?

If you can answer this too I will accept your answer ;)