# Do i need to dispose page / page properties before using Frame.Navigate()?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am building windows store 8.1 application. for page navigation i simply using :

`Frame.Navigate(typeof(DestiantionPage),param)`

But when navigate to the same page over and over. I got a memory leak. Im checking through 'analyze'>'performance and diagnostic' on visual studio 2013.

I saw that the memory used by the page im talking about **is growing every time i navigate to** that page.

when i trace the code, the destructor of that class page was NOT called when i navigate to another page. **why was it happened?**

i wonder **if i need to do something like disposing my page or properties?**

note : i also have some subscribed events (**do i need to unsubscribe them?**)

EDIT : 
i have tried setting `NavigationCacheMode` into `this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307375/navigating-to-page-increases-memory-usage-windows-universal-8-1) but **it still** have memory leak.

Comment: Have you changed the value of the `NavigationCacheMode` property on your page?

Comment: @KooKiz yes i have, i'm editting the question. am i doing it right?

Comment: my bad, i change it to `this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;` and memory leak problem is handled. :))